# Bootstrap Tags Input objects and json

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Boorstrap Tag Input control as located here:

http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

In my controller, I am creating a list of my SelectListItems:

```
       var tags = new List<SelectListItem>();

        tags.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = "1",
            Text = "Craig"
        });

        tags.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = "2",
            Text = "Lister"
        });


        model.Tags = tags;
```

I then pass that to my model, where 'Tag' is a:

> public IEnumerable Tags { get; set; }

On my view, I render the control:

```
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="control-label text-right">Tags:</label>
                            <br />
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Tags, new { @class= "form-control txtTags", @data_role= "tagsinput" })

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

However, instead of seeing the tags, the control renders as a drop down list with my two items.

Comment: You cant bind a form control to a collection of complex objects. The property you bind to needs to be `int[] Tags` and then you pass the json when you attach the plugin. You also need generate a `<select multiple>` element if your wanting to display the text property but bind to the value property so use `@DropDownListFor()` and pass the tags as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` rather than json

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - I have modified my question based on your answer. My control now renders as a drop down list. Am I missing something?

Comment: You would need `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, Model.Tags)` where property `SelectedTags` is `int[] SelectedTags` and then in the script `$('#SelectedTags').tagsinput();`

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now the control is rendering, but showing the ids, as opposed to the text. When I post back, the model has a 'SelectedTags' and a 'Tags' property. Tags is null, while 'Selected Tags' has the ids.

Comment: Yes `Tags` will be null. You do not (and should not) generate an input for each property of each `SelectListItem`. If you need to return the view, you need to repopulate the `Tags` property. I think you can control which properties are used for the value and display text using the `itemValue` and `itemText` options of `tagsinput()`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - looks like I may have an issue then, as using objects doesn't seem to allow for new additional items to be added that were not in the original list. I need to be able to add new items that were not in the original list passed to the view.

Comment: OK, In that case you need to use the `add` method, for example `$('#SelectedTags').tagsinput('add', { id: 1, text: 'some tag' });`. And you can always do something like `var tags = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tags))');` to serialize the existing tags and then `$('#SelectedTags').tagsinput('add', tags);` (although I'm not sure if the `add` method allows you to add an array, or if you would need to loop the array and add one at a time). If you did do this, then you would just use `IEnumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>` for the select list and `Tags` can be `List<tagObject>`